# Error handling with PHP classes

Tags: php

I'm working on my first "public" class, meaning that i will release it under the GPL for everyone. I'm giving extra-attention to documentation, however, i gave zero attention to error handling. How do you guys suggest that i do that? Throw exceptions? I never worked with error handling before, just the basic try catch with PDO and others.

Comment: Totally depends on what kind of class it is and what it does

Comment: GPL sucks. If you want people to adopt it, use something like MIT

Comment: That's not the questions, Gordon, although i appreciate your comment. My class is a simple form generation class. Errors occur depending on the input sent to the class, therefore i wanted to provide some feedback when something "bad" occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions are (in general) the most elegant way of error handling. You definitely do not want to use some kind of error-codes, since it requires much more code and effort to check for those.

Comment: Should i just start throwing exceptions in place of my old die()'s?

Comment: @Billy: Thats right. Make sure to give your exceptions meaningful names and messages. This simplifies debugging a lot and makes it easier for others to understand your class.